# While installing cargo-contract --version 2.0.0-alpha.3, I got error

Tags: ink, cargo-contract

I am using `cargo install cargo-contract --version 2.0.0-alpha.3` to install `2.0.0-alpha.3`, I got **`error: failed to compile cargo-contract v2.0.0-alpha.3, intermediate artifacts can be found at /var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/cargo-installPMiOKW`** error. Does cargo-contract `Pre-release` installation has issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because some dependencies got updated (breaking changes).

You should use this to lock the dependencies version:

```
cargo install --force --locked cargo-contract --version 2.0.0-alpha.3
```